# How to override core files into app/code/Magento folder in magento2

Tags: overrides, magento2.2.2, override-model

How do I override core files in `app/code/Magento` folder in Magento 2?

I want to change core functionality so I need to override core files in the app/code/Magento folder instead of directly changing that core files.

Core file:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Export/Product.php

Overriden at:

> app/code/Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Export/Product.php

But it is not working. I don't know how to implement this task. Can you please help me?

Comment: check my answer and let me know if any issue.

Comment: have you checked my solution ? @dileep

Comment: Hi @ Divyesh, I have checked your solution It is not working. Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi @ Divyesh, Please check my screenshot. https://prnt.sc/jng8ek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can override model using plugin features in Magento2
>
> for that Create a custom module and in di.xml put code like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product">
        <plugin name="override-module-export-product" type="Nimesh\HelloWorld\Plugin\Export\Product" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

You can override model function using before, after & around method. In below example, We can override export function behavior using before and after method

> Create class file like this
>   (app/code/Nimesh/HelloWorld/Plugin/Export/Product.php)

```
namespace Nimesh/HelloWorld/Plugin/Export;

class Product
{   

    public function beforeExport(\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product $product)
    {
        /******put your logic *******/            
    }


    public function afterExport(\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product $product)
    { 
        /********put your logic ********/   
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Hi @ Nimesh, Actually my issue is when I export products I got the error message "Please correct the data sent value." Because of this error "Call to a member function getName() on null in  vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Export/Product.php". So I don't want to change core files. Please let me know the solution for this post without modifying core files

Comment: Hi @ Nimesh, Can you please help me?

Comment: Yes sure. I am honored to help you.

Comment: I think you got getName() on null in "initCategories()" function so my suggestion is thet use beforeInitCategories() and set the logic as per that.

Comment: HI @ Nimesh, it is not working.

Comment: what kind of changes have you done?

Comment: Hi @ Nimesh,   protected function initCategories()
    {  I have changed this function of protected function beforeInitCategories but it is not working.

Comment: Hi @ Nimesh,  Can you please help me with this task?

Comment: Have you debugged with your plugin function? Please check it executes or not?

Comment: Hi @ Nimesh, I want override core files like magento1 in magento2.In magento1 override root folder is app/code/local like that, Is it an option to override core files.

Comment: as per requirement if it's necessary to override file like Magento 1 core then you can use Preference in Magento 2, But if only change some behavior of specific function then you need to override then use Plugin.

Comment: Depends on need

Comment: Hi @ Nimesh, How to create a plugin. Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi @ Nimesh, I am waiting for your answer. Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi @ Nimesh, help me with this task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78011/discussion-between-nimesh-and-dileep-kumar).

Comment: Hi@ Nimesh, Please check my screenshot. https://prnt.sc/jng8ek

Comment: Hi @ Nimesh, I need your help. Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi @ Nimesh, Help me this task.

Answer (score 1):

Create simple module and override model file.

**Step 1.**

Create a `di.xml` file in a following directory `Company/CatalogImportExport/etc/`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product" type="Company\CatalogImportExport\Model\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Export\Product" />

</config>
```

**Step 2**

```
<?php

namespace Company\CatalogImportExport\Model\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Export;


class Product extends \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product
{
        public function __construct()
        {
            echo "Model Rewrite Working"; die();
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ Nikunj Vadariya , I have followed your steps but that override file is not affecting and the response came from core file only.

Comment: Hi @ Nikunj Vadariya, Hi @ Nimesh, I want override core files like magento1 in magento2.In magento1 override root folder is app/code/local like that, Is it an option to override core files.

Answer (score 1):

it can easy

1. Move/Copy to core module to - **app/code/Magento/Wishlist**
2. List item edit **composer.json** and add

> "replace": {
>                   "magento/module-wishlist": "*"
>               },

more info by link - https://www.integer-net.com/removing-unused-core-modules-from-magento-2-the-right-way/

3. run command SSH - *composer update*
4. run command SSH - *php bin/magento setup:upgrade*
5. check and remove module in **vendor/magento/module-wishlist**

Now, you can edit/remove logic of Magento standard modules

:)

Answer (score -1):

You have to create one new module in that "code" folder and override that Model's Product.php in that module.

Comment: Hi @ H.K Suthar, Is it mandatory to create the separate module for overriding above core file? I want to use default app/code/Magento to override.

Comment: Yes its mandetory

Comment: Hi @ H.K.Suthar, Hi @ Nimesh, I want override core files like magento1 in magento2.In magento1 override root folder is app/code/local like that, Is it an option to override core files.